# Python subprocess popen pending

Tags: python

First my english is too bad.Please don't mind.

I'm using `subprocess.Popen()` executes command `service xxx start`.Service my `thrift service`.

For normal, is exit execute.But my programme is pending.

But i execute `service memcached start`,is return normal.

My service shell to running programme:

```
daemon $abs_path/../bin/$XXX_SERVER  "> /dev/null&"
```

I'm execute command in shell is return to normal.

I using `pdb.set_trace()` trace to subprocess source code, find pending at file

subprocess.py #1211

```
rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(read_set, write_set, [])
```

Current params is:

```
read_set = [<open file '<fdopen>', mode 'rb' at 0x7f59327b7d20>]

write_set = []
```

And `read_set` object is open `stderr` pipe.

Before pending, `stdout` has read normal result.But reading `stderr` pipe is pending.

How can i do.

Thanks all.

Comment: Can you share your subprocess.Popen() code?

Comment: OK!!I'm finded a solution!I'm using deamon module fixed this bug.Module url:[daemon module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/)

Comment: @gae123 subprocess module is system module。My python version is 2.6.6